# Relation of characteristic of a field and a domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be two integral domains and $\varphi : A \longrightarrow B$ a ring homomorphism. Assume that $A$ is a field, how are the characteristics of $A$ and $B$ related?

What I found so far:

$ker(\varphi)$ is an ideal, and since $A$ is a field, the only two ideals the kernel can be are either $A$ itself or $\{0_A\} = (0_A)$.

If $ker(\varphi) = (0_A)$, then $\varphi$ is injective, and therefore $char(A) = char(B)$ (which I already proved before).

If $ker(\varphi) = A$, then $\forall x \in A: \varphi(x) = 0_B$. My idea was to say that $\varphi(1_A) = 1_B$, therefore $1_B = 0_B$ and call it a contradiction, but $B$ isn't necessarily a field, so I don't know that $1_B \neq 0_B$.

What conclusion can I draw here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual convention is that for integral domains $1 \neq 0$, thus your argument is fine.

Recall that the only ring with $1=0$ is the trivial ring $R = \{0\}$, which is usually not considered as an integral domain.

Comment: Ok. I was confused because in the definition of a field we had that $0 \neq 1$, so I thought there are cases where this isn't true. So either $0_B \neq 1_B$, or $B = {0_B}$. You say that $B$ is not considered a domain then, usually. But isn't it technically still one? And if so, then in that case I can't conclude, right?

Comment: It is a matter of the  definition you use. Usually it is just excluded see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain I cannot know what is your definition of a domain. But most do not consider the trivial ring a domain. What is true though is that the trivial ring is a ring without non-zero zero-divisor but this is in fact *not* the technical definition of domain (usually). You really need to check your definition. The answer depends on it. If ever a domain can be the trvial ring the answer is the characteristic of B is the same as that of A or it is 1 (which is equivalent to B={0]).

Comment: I just checked the definition in our course and though it doesn't say that $0 \neq 1$, later in another example we used it though, so I guess he assumed that $0 \neq 1$. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible it is implicit in the definition. For example it is implicit in $|R| \ge 2$ or in  $\{0\}$ is prime ideal of $R$.